# UTF-8 Encoding Problem in Java Text Output

Tags: java, utf-8, nlp

I've been working on testing various solutions for a Khmer Unicode Wordbreaker (Khmer does not have spaces between words which makes spell checking and grammar checking difficult, as well as converting from legacy Khmer into Khmer Unicode).

I was given some source code which is now online ( http://www.whitemagicsoftware.com/software/java/wordsplit/ ) that seems promising.  The author was kind enough to give the source, but he is very busy writing a book and is unable to troubleshoot.

I am testing the code on a very small scale, and I am having trouble with the output.

Here is the input:

> ជាដែលនឹងបានមាន

Here's the resulting output:

> ជារ���លនឹងបានមាន,ជា រ���ល នឹង បាន
>   មាន

The words are actually split correctly, but one word is jumbled.
The output should look like this:

> ជាដែលនឹងបានមាន, ជា ដែល នឹង បាន មាន

Does anyone have an insight as to why the output is garbled?

Here's the code with a very small Khmer lexicon and words to be split: http://www.sbbic.org/khmerwordsplit.zip

And here's how to run it:

> java -jar wordsplit.jar
>   khmerlexicon.csv khmercolumns.txt >>
>   results.txt

I am very grateful to the stackoverflow community for all the help you have provided with this project so far - I hope a solution is soon to be found!

Comment: Its not an answer to your question but I recently read a very good blog post on Unicode by a SO user (BalusC). Might be helpful.  http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that it works correctly when system encoding is configured as UTF-8:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar wordsplit.jar khmerlexicon.csv khmercolumns.txt >> results.txt
```

Perhaps input file is assumed to be in system encoding. Read [BalusC's post mentioned in the comments](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) to see how to perform input/output independent from system encoding.

Comment: Awesome thank you - I didn't think that was the issue because some of the UTF-8 characters were coming through.  I will definitely look at BalusC's post.  Thanks again!