# convert charset in windows and linux

Tags: java, linux, character-encoding, utf-16, smpp

I'm building SMPP gateway that gets byte[] array of indian chars and converts it to readable string that forwarded by email.
In Win machine, this code is working:

```
byte[] data= ....;
shortMessage = new String(data, GSMCharset.forName("UTF-16"));
```

In Linux however, its give rubbish.

I tried other charset options, but all give me nothing.
Any ideas how to make it work on Linux.

(The DataCoding == 8)

Comment: What is `DataCoding`? Also, you should tag this `java`.

Comment: Tn'x, I added java tag, DataCoding is smpp property that indicate the data encoding, may help to SMPP experts.

Comment: Is the array of bytes the same on both platforms?

Comment: the array is the same: 

    9, 22, 9, 65, 9, 54, 9, 22, 9, 44, 9, 48, 9, 64, 

in Windows I get:  खुशखबरी

in linux ???????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the encoding of the output is controlled by the encoding of the source file. Unless specified at compile time ([How can I specify the encoding of Java source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248267/how-can-i-specify-the-encoding-of-java-source-files)), the default encoding is inherited from the OS.

I am guessing the Windows machine you used had a default encoding that caused the output you are expecting, while the Linux machine did not. See this question for a similar issue reported - [Charset of Java source file and failing test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328956/charset-of-java-source-file-and-failing-test).

I was able to reproduce the behavior. Also found a fix - changing the encoding of the source file. Read on for details.

I ran the following code in two different encodings.

```
System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset().toString());
byte[] data = new byte[] {9, 22, 9, 65, 9, 54, 9, 22, 9, 44, 9, 48, 9, 64};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
System.out.println(new String(data, "UTF-16"));
```

### Using default encoding of OS

In my case, it was "MacRoman" on my mac. The output is this:

```
MacRoman
[9, 22, 9, 65, 9, 54, 9, 22, 9, 44, 9, 48, 9, 64]
???????
```

### Using UTF-8 encoding

I changed the encoding of the source file (see the "Properties" of the source file). Ran again. The output is this:

```
UTF-8
[9, 22, 9, 65, 9, 54, 9, 22, 9, 44, 9, 48, 9, 64]
खुशखबरी
```

Comment: It seems you are right, when running my code, I get US-ASCCI as the defaultCharset.
However, also after I changed the text file encoding to UTF-8 in the eclipse file properties is the same - show US-ASCCI.

Comment: Try using "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" command line parameter with java. Shown here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885114/utf-8-encoding-problem-in-java-text-output. Also can be font issue - http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html.

Comment: added -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to the command that runs the jar file, everything is working now, Thanks!